# Python matplotlib doesn't show full date on mouse hover

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a dataframe with **date index** and **temperature values**:

```
Date     Temperature
2015-10-21     9.118
2015-10-22     9.099
2015-10-23     8.945
2015-10-26     8.848
2015-10-27     8.848
2015-10-28     8.829
2015-10-30     8.935
2015-11-02     9.302
2015-11-03     9.012
2015-11-04     9.109
...
2017-10-16    10.160
2017-10-17    10.180
2017-10-18    10.140
2017-10-19    10.370
2017-10-20    10.360
```

Plotting it using interactive %matplotlib notebook shows the temperature, year/month on the bottom right, **but omits the day**.

```
#%matplotlib notebook
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_axis = df.index.tolist()
y_axis = df['temperature'].tolist()

plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I get it to show the day? Any format is fine, but preferably '01-Jan-2017'.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `format_coord` method of the axes to specify the format of the text shown in the status bar or lower left corner of the notebook figure.

In case this is to be a datetime object, the use of a `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter` is reasonable. The format specifier would then be `"%d-%b-%Y"` for something like '01-Jan-2017'.

```
import matplotlib.dates
datefmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%d-%b-%Y")
fmt = lambda x,y : "{}, {:.5g}".format(datefmt(x), y)
plt.gca().format_coord = fmt
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler version of the original answer by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is to use the `fmt_xdata` attribute:

```py
import matplotlib.dates
plt.gca().fmt_xdata = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%d-%b-%Y")
```

That attribute lets you set the formatter specifically for the x-data, so you won't alter the y-data formatting, and it removes the need to have an intermediary formatting function. The `fmt_xdata` attribute is used by the `format_xdata` method (see docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_xdata.html)), which in turn is used by the `format_coord` method mentioned in the original answer (source code [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9765379ce6e7343070e815afc0988874041b98e2/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L4142-L4147)).